# How can I send the fields in the json body in a parametric way to node js api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest

The rest api I use with express js below sends an electronic signature request to the defined user mail. He makes this request with his email address in the json body. The e-mail addresses to be sent may be different. How can I send the `email_address` and `name` fields in the `opts` body in a parametric way to api? The main problem I have is how do I send the parameters of `email_address` and `name` to json body parametrically. I don't want to send hard coded.

***Express JS API:***

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const hellosign = require('hellosign-sdk')({ key: 'key123' });
const fs = require('fs');

hellosign.account.update({
    callback_url: process.env.HOST_URL+'api/callback'
}).then((res) => {
    // handle response
    console.log("--- sign res ---");
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
    // handle error
    console.log(err)
});


router.post('/sign',(req,res)=>{

    res.send('Sign request is called');

    const opts = {
        test_mode: 1,
        title: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
        subject: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
        message: 'Please sign this pdf.',
        signers: [
            {
                email_address: 'example@gmail.com',
                name: 'Mr Okoreni'
            }
        ],
        files: ['nda.pdf']
    };

    hellosign.signatureRequest.send(opts).then((res) => {
        // handle response
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(err)
    });
});

router.post('/callback',(req,res)=>{

    res.send('Hello API Event Received');
    console.log('callback request is called');
    try{
        res.send(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
        console.log(res.body);
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

});

router.get('/download/',(req,res)=>{

    res.send('download request is called');
    try {
        console.log('download request is called');

        var signatureRequestId = 'sign123';
        hellosign.signatureRequest.download(signatureRequestId, { file_type: 'zip' }, (err, res) => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream("./downloads/"+signatureRequestId+"files.zip");

            res.pipe(file);

            file.on('finish', () => {
                file.close();
                console.log("finish");
            });
        });

    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Server is listening...")
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why not have the client that uses the `/sign` endpoint send the request ID for the `/download` endpoing, that way you can know which request they're talking about? Or is that the question you're asking? Sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: /sign sends a request to the relevant person for signature. /download, on the other hand, saves the document whose signature process has been completed. We cannot download a document before the signing process is over.

Comment: The main problem I have is how do I send the parameters of mail_address and name to json body parametrically. I don't want to send hard coded.

Comment: What's wrong with hard coded? Are you worried about information security?

Comment: Why is not POSTing with email and name not sufficient here? Its not entirely clear what youre attempting to solve here that would otherwise we solved via common req/res bodies.

Comment: I want to keep it parametrically, how do I keep it as a global variable, if you know, can you add it as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally depends where you're getting the parameterised fields from

From the request..

```
const opts = {
    test_mode: 1,
    title: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
    subject: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
    message: 'Please sign this pdf.',
    signers: [
        {
            email_address: req.email_address,
            name: req.name,
        },
    ],
    files: ['nda.pdf'],
}
```